# what will happen if a proper noun comes after a determiner, will it get capitalized?

Tags: proper-nouns

like for example if someone's husband's name is "Jake" and it is used in "my Jake" should it be capitalized since it is a proper noun?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you think it would not be?

Comment: Yes (https://www.grammarly.com/blog/capitalization-rules/#:~:text=The%20capitalization%20rules%20for%20titles%20of%20books,%20movies,,like%20is),%20all%20adjectives,%20and%20all%20proper%20nouns.) look at number (2) it says "My mom is not going to like this." mom isn't capitalized

Comment: That's because 'mom' here is a synonym for 'my mother', not a form of address. If the 'my'  was omitted, 'Mom' would be capitalised because it would replace her name. _Actual_ names are always capitalised.

Comment: You would not capitalise "My brother is not going to like this" or "My friend is not going to like this" either.

Comment: so why do we capitalize "Jake" in "my Jake"?

Comment: Jake is a proper noun.

Comment: @Davo, but the word "mom" and "brother" or "friend" can also be proper noun so why don't we capitalize them there?

Comment: What has your research shown? New questions should be posted as questions, not comments.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it should be capitalized.  Names are always capitalized.